# Need help looping Macro that cut/inserts and deletes a cell range based on a selected row

Tags: macros, loopingselector

This Macro is used to cut, insert and delete a cell range section of a workbook.

The problem I was trying to solve and gave up with the lack of response in another thread is why copying multiple non-adjacent rows to the MS clipboard often loses their row line-breaks when pasting.

E.g. Since trying to paste 3 non-adjacent rows into row 10, 11 and 12, often puts all 3 rows into row 10 with one row in fields A10-P10, the next row in Q10-AF10 and the last row into AG10-AV10...

I edited the Macro below to fix this mistake when this happens.

So, for example, I can now highlight row 10 and run the macro to cut/insert the fields Q10-AF10 to A11-P11 and delete/shift left the blank fields now in Q10-AF10.

I'm hoping for help to loop this process until there's no data outside Column A-P. In this case, no data outside cell P10.

```
Sub FixAllOnLine1OneRowAtATimeInsertToNextRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = ActiveSheet
    Set pasteSheet = ActiveSheet

    copySheet.Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
    Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Offset(1).Select

    pasteSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Columns("Q:AF").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made some headway. I just have one super easy issue and then I need to loop it.

The first issue is that it cuts Column Q:AF correct of the row I've highlighted and shifts the entire Column Q:AF to the left, but it INSERTS the cut cells into the fixed range, A2:P2. I want to INSERT the cut cells down ONE row from my selection. I KNOW this is a couple characters in the Offset, I just can't get it.

Then, once it's working properly...say I highlight row 10, it cuts Q10:AF10 and instead INSERTS the cells into A11:P11 and shifts "Q:AF" to the left, then I need to figure out how to get it to loop until there's no more data to right of Column P. When this problem occurs pasting multiple rows from the clipboard all into the first row losing the row line-breaks, it's always quite a few rows.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!
Mark

```
    Sub FixAllOnLine1OneRowAtATimeInsertToNextRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lNextRow As Long

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        ws.Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy 'Copy the row of the selected cell from Q:AF

        ws.Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row & ":AF" &  ActiveCell.Row).Offset(1).Select 'Select the cells you have just copied.  Not needed

        ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert xlShiftDown ' Paste the copied values in to column "A" on next row?
        'lNextRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Get Next Row number
        'Range("A" & lNextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Range("Q:AF").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        'Columns("Q:AF").Select
        'Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Activate 'Added to move active cell up one row to run it again for multiple groups to apply fix.

    End Sub
```

Comment: I was certain that the issue of a small change to the Offset to move, in the example above, the cut cell range Q10:AF10 inserted one row below into cell range A11:P11 rather than B2:P2 would be easily fixable. :-(  The offset functions (x,y) stuff I'm still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in another direction just in case someone from the engines needs it...

```
Sub ReduceNoOfColumns()

Dim iRow As Integer 'Row to be manipulated
Dim iRowToPasteTo 'Row number to paste the copied cells
Dim iCurCol As Integer 'Current Column number of first cell with a value to cut
Dim NoOfCols As Integer 'integer to hold max number of columns
Dim sAddress As String

    iRow = ActiveCell.Row
    iRowToPasteTo = iRow + 1
    NoOfCols = 16 'Set this number to the total number of columns you wish to have (in your case 16)
    iCurCol = NoOfCols + 1

    Do Until Cells(iRow, iCurCol).Value = ""  'Keep looping until we get to an empty column
        sAddress = ColNoToLetter(iCurCol) & iRow & ":" & ColNoToLetter(iCurCol + NoOfCols - 1) & iRow
        Rows(iRowToPasteTo & ":" & iRowToPasteTo).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range(sAddress).Copy
        Range("A" & iRowToPasteTo).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        Range(sAddress).Clear

        iCurCol = iCurCol + NoOfCols
        iRowToPasteTo = iRowToPasteTo + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function ColNoToLetter(iCol As Integer) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, iCol).Address(True, False), "$")
ColNoToLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```